# Resolve conflict between two pan gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have the following hierarchy:

- View

  - Subview

Each of those views has `UIPanGestureRecognizer` assigned. Outer pan gesture recognizer is only interested in vertical panning, so I have the delegate method implemented for that:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:panGestureRecognizer.view];
    return fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x);
}
```

However Subview's pan gesture always takes precedence in recognition. Is there any way to make outer pan gesture recognizer to recognize first and then if it fails, pan gesture from subview can take over?

I tried simultaneous recognition and it works, but then both recognizers start panning:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 

    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since iOS 7, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Protocol has already declared two delegate methods for your need, you can either use
|*gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:*|
or 
|*gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:*| but in the opposite way.

The following snippet is my UIPanGestureRecognizer delegate implementation:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:panGestureRecognizer.view];
    return fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x);
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    if (otherGestureRecognizer == panGestureOfSubView) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I truly believed that `shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer` works the other way around, that's why it apparently did not work for me.

Comment: I have no idea why but your answer works for me... Apparently it shifts some priority between gesture recognizers and actually the one that supposed to fail but recognized first, fails the other one...

Comment: @Andy, the first argument of the two delegate methods is always the delegator, since there are only two gestures in this case, the delegate method in the snippet above return YES only when the gestureRecognizer parameter attached to superview and the otherGestureRecognizer parameter attached  to  subview. In this case, according to the snippet, the gesture attached to subview will only be recognized after the gesture attached to superview failed.

Answer (score 1):

This code might be helpful. It's what I wrote to allow dragging for a specific view, but not for its subviews:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        if gestureRecognizer == longTouchGesture && otherGestureRecognizer == panTouchGesture && gestureRecognizer.view?.hitTest(gestureRecognizer.locationInView(gestureRecognizer.view), withEvent: nil) == self {
            print("returning true")
            return true
        }
        print("returning false")
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift version of accepted answer**

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ panGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let velocity = panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: panGestureRecognizer.view)
    return abs(Float(velocity.y)) > abs(Float(velocity.x))
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if otherGestureRecognizer == panGestureOfSubView {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `===`, not `==` on the line `if otherGestureRecognizer == panGestureOfSubView {`.

Comment: As @HangarRash pointed out, assuming you want to check if the references point to the same instance in memory, you must use `===`, since the gesture recognizer is a class/reference type. The Apple docs used `==`, but that is probably a typo. To compare the dynamic types of two instances, use `type(of:)`.